# Minimum row count to create Non-clustered index in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

Just wondering, what is the minimum number of records should present in the database such that non-clustered index will give advantage on simple SQL query.

I have a table with 100K records and my query is simple as below.

```
SELECT
   a,
   b,
   c,
   d
FROM
   Table
WHERE 
   d in ('@d')
```

My table is updating only once in a day. So is it beneficiary to create a non-clustered index on 'd' column?

Comment: you have the tables. You have the data. You could apply the index and measure its effect. We can not.

Comment: Do you have the space to add the index? If that's not an issue, you should probably just add it and then let the query optimiser figure out whether it's sensible to use it or not. But as Damien says, this is more of a question for you than for us. We just don't have enough information (data cardinality, etc.) to say what's beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the table, you would be adding a "heap" index on your table. This is a non-clustered index on a table, where there is no clustered index.

For a table with over 100,000 rows, this would generally degrade the performance of your query, however, without having a good look at the execution plans and no DDL posted, it's pretty much just guess work.

Want to speed up the query? Consider adding a clustered index to the table and then add a non-clustered index to the column you're searching on. I'd also keep track of index statistics and fragmentation on a regular basis if the table gets updated as often as once per day. In the event this becomes a problem, you can always rebuild the indexes for maximum efficiency.

As I said, guess work, but don't add non-clustered indexes to a large table. It will still table scan, only slower. [Read more here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213609.aspx)

Comment: Do you have independent verification of your claim that a non-clustered index on a heap over a certain size degrades performance? I find it hard to bribe that a table scan would be more efficient than an index seek or scan followed by a RID lookup. But I'm willing to learn something today.

Comment: The table described is a text-book "don't use a heap table" scenario. Once a day inserts/updates on a clustered indexed table is fine if you keep track of fragmentation like I said. While querying a heap with that many rows is surely going to be slower since it's not ordered in any way. Keeping that table as a heap means you're doing a full scan on the table each time, where a clustered table wouldn't. But again as I said, it might be that the difference is minuscule, because I can't see any DDL and I don't have access to his environment. Thought this was basic DB design?

Comment: What your saying though is that a non-clustered index on a heap cannot be used to efficiently locate matching rows. If that's the case, why does SQL Server allow you to create said index? If it can never be used, shouldn't there be some giant error on index creation saying "the storage engine has no way to use this index"? Also, I have a couple of heaps in my environment that have non-clustered indexes on then and they get used.

Comment: Also, pulling the "thought this was basic" is not a great way to keep the conversation constructive.

Comment: I fail to see what I was "pulling"? This is basic database design. On a `SELECT` query intensive table, a clustered index is always the best route. How can this not be understood?

Comment: If something is "basic" or "obvious", by definition it should be easy to demonstrate empirically. Thus far in the conversation, you haven't done so. And don't get me wrong: I'm not saying a heap is better *for this implementation*. But your statement is stronger than that saying that heaps imply the inability to leverage a non-clustered index. And that's what I'm challenging you to demonstrate.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I mean is that for this particular scenario, a covering index might do more harm than good. I don't really have time to set it up myself, however there are many articles online describing the problems I've outlined here. Like this: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/02/27/reasons-why-you-may-not-want-to-use-a-heap